# How to get rid of gradient color system in Tableau line chart

Tags: charts, tableau-api

I'm getting gradient colored lines over the chart.

How can I bring them to single color?

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question without seeing what is going on. Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a measure in your color shelf;  remove the measure from the shelf, and then set a color for the lines.  This [part](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/windows/en-us/help.htm#viewparts_marks.html%3FTocPath%3DBuilding%2520Data%2520Views%7CParts%2520of%2520the%2520View%7CMarks%7C_____0) of the Desktop User Guide explains the marks card

Comment: @BJMyers sorry about the flag, realized he edited the answer after the flag